# I have two Go functions that I'd expect to behave the same, but give different results. Trying to understand why

Tags: go, binary-search-tree

I was writing a binary search tree traversal when I came across a problem, and then a slight syntax change fixed it but I don't understand why it wasn't working in the first palce. The two code examples I provide I would expect to run the exact same way but they don't.

One sets the curr variable to it's left node curr.left, then recursively calls the InOrderRecursive, while the other calls InOrderRecursive directly on curr.left itself.

```
type BST struct {
    value int
    left *BST
    right *BST
}
```

Does not work (This does return but with the wrong values):

```
func (tree *BST) InOrderRecursive(values []int) []int {
    curr := tree

    if curr.left != nil {
        curr = curr.left
        values = curr.InOrderRecursive(values)
    }
    values = append(values, curr.value)
    if curr.right != nil {
        curr = curr.right
        values = curr.InOrderRecursive(values)
    }
    return values
}
```

Works (returns the correct values):

```
func (tree *BST) InOrderRecursive(values []int) []int {
    curr := tree

    if curr.left != nil {
        values = curr.left.InOrderRecursive(values)
    }
    values = append(values, curr.value)
    if curr.right != nil {
        values = curr.right.InOrderRecursive(values)
    }
    return values
}
```

Could someone please explain the difference in these two code examples and the reason for the different behavior?

Comment: The working one checks `left` and `right` fields of the nodes because `curr` is not changed. The one that doesn't work changes `curr` if `curr.left` is not `nil`, so the `right` field of the original `curr` will be skipped (will not be checked).

Comment: The "works" version has a bug: It fails to append the right branch to the other collected results - instead it overwrites their results.

Comment: @icza Ahh ok that does make sense. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The first version has a slight bug. If `curr.left` is not nil in version 1, then `values = append(values, curr.value)` will append the left child node's value to the list, not the current node, since `curr` is now equal to `curr.left` outside of the if scope. More specifically,

```golang
func (tree *BST) InOrderRecursive(values []int) []int {
    curr := tree

    if curr.left != nil {
        curr = curr.left
        values = curr.InOrderRecursive(values)
    }
    // curr here will take on the node's left child value if
    // it's not nil (bug).
    values = append(values, curr.value)
    // That issue will cascade to here as well (if the OG curr.left
    // != nil), we're now checking the left child node's right child. 
    if curr.right != nil {
        curr = curr.right
        values = curr.InOrderRecursive(values)
    }
    // The result of the right recursive call is not appended to the
    // `values` list. (bug)
    return values
}
```